# Strict case in content URL alias

Tags: 7, path-aliases

(Pathauto: Leave case the same as source token values)

When I create a node with "Nullam vehicula pharetra" as title, the Pathauto module will create `/content/Nullam-vehicula-pharetra` as URL alias. But we can browse the same content with a different URL case, such as `/content/NULLam-vehicula-pharetra`.

How do I make Drupal strict on the URL alias case?

Wikipedia is good example about what I need. Two different case request return different contents:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DruPal

Comment: As defined in all the relevant RFCs, the path portion of a URL is case sensitive. Drupal happens to ignore case in the path, but that's a feature of Drupal, not a characteristic of URLs. I don't know of an easy way to make Drupal 7 case-sensitive, and if you did this I suspect it would impact a lot of Drupal modules which might assume the path is always lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't use pathauto,  Drupal7 can not differentiate case sensitive urls. This 'issue' is not code related,  but it has to be with the database collation. non-binary string comparison are case-insensitive by default.

A solution could be to set the 'alias' columns (menu_router.path, url_alias.alias) to binary (case-sensitive).

Be aware that changing the structure of those two columns in existing sites could result in broken links because paths/alias would have to match base on case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Blanca.

Wikipedia, and wikis in general, use a completely different system of creating and linking pages.

The following doesn't answer your question but it might help with your approach.

To avoid search engine ranking issues I always select "Change to lower case" in /admin/config/search/path/settings, as well as use [Global 
Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) with "Case Sensitive URL Checking".

So if a you visited domain.com/Page you'd be redirected to domain.com/page.

This seems like a more logical approach to me. I don't think any user would expect to see different content according to case sensitivity. i.e. to take this a step further StackExchange.com is no different to stackexchange.com.

Of course, in your case, this might not make any sense.